# EXCEL COM Add-In: Automatic Log in

Tags: python, excel, vba, com, add-in

Im hoping you can help. We have a 3rd party add-in that requires you to go into the 'Add-In' tab, hover over it and select in the list 'Log-In'. then one has to enter a username and password. And press log in. The issue is, the userform isn't in the VBA editor so I cant find out what boxes ect to fill in / click.

Is there any way to automate this? With VBA / Python / VBS / C++

Comment: It's an XLAM add-in? What function does it call when Login is clicked? Can you find the function and put a breakpoint in it (nevermind the userform)?

Comment: I wish (unless I am being stupid) when you look into the VBA editor, there is nothing in the project window even though it is loaded. The file where it is referenced in the Add-Ins Options section is a file with a number of XLM documents

Comment: When you setup the add-in initially, what file are you selecting? or did that magically happen with some setup program?

Comment: They sent a program which installs it. Sorry if it seems i'm being obnoxious - I am not, I just don't know HTH to fix it.

Comment: I clicked on the program, it instructed me to close excel then inserted the folder eith the XML files into my appdata folder

Comment: You are probably out of luck, but dont take my word for it... someone else might have an idea now that you've answered some basic questions. If you are able to tell us what the name of the program is or how to get ahold of it, that may help someone (not me) figure out something.

Comment: The only thing I see is a 'debug.txt' file. In it you can see `2019-11-15 07:15:29,547 [1] ERROR TXTSSSQ.FrmLogin -  Failed to authenticate: Invalid username or password` and `2019-11-15 07:15:43,099 [1] DEBUG TXTSSSQ.FrmLogin - Login successfull! User sam.harper@yahoo.com logged into TOKYO`